# jquery write a style using variable

Tags: jquery, coding-style, var

OK, once again I need help.
I have managed to pass a variable in a query string from one page to another using this guys code:
http://snipplr.com/users/Roshambo/

That all works great and I can see that it works by using an alert on the second page to test it:

```
var byName = $.getUrlVar('id');
alert(byName);
```

However... what I would like to do is take that var and paste it into a css rule, so that this would essentially happen:

```
div#byName{
    display: block;
}
```

I've read that using document.write is frowned heavily upon and to be honest, I just don't know what I'm doing. How can I get the div with an id the same as the var to display as a block?

Any help greatly greatly appreciated. I am at wits end with this project! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply css style using the .css() jQuery command as

```
var byName = $.getUrlVar('id'); 
$("#" + byName).css("display", "block");
```

Look at: http://api.jquery.com/css/

or use addClass() and define your style in css file

```
var byName = $.getUrlVar('id');
$("#" + byName).addClass("example");
```

and

```
div.example{
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
var byName = $.getUrlVar('id');
$("#" + byName).css("display", "block");
```

Comment: Perfect! Same as the above answer, it seems I can only tick one as the accepted answer though :( sorry dude, but thank you very much for replying.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just getaway with `.addClass('foo')` where the class already has the style?